# Failed to build gnome-system-tools in Fedora 28 [glib-compile-schemas not found]

Tags: fedora, configure

I downloaded and untared package named `gnome-system-tools-3.0.0`. When typing the command `./configure` I've got the following error massage:

```
configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.
```

I've tried to update glib. I have the file `glib-compile-schemas` in `/usr/bin` directory.

OS: Fedora 28

Comment: It sounds to me as if you haven't actually installed it, only untar'd it - please check this point.

Comment: I didn't claim that I've installed it.

Comment: ok, was just checking!

Answer (score 0):

These tools were last updated in 2011. That is seven and a half years ago. In computer time, that's.... ancient. You would probably need corresponding versions of other parts of GNOME and of system libraries from that era to even get it to build, and even if you did that, the actual *features* for system management are unlikely to work.

Instead, I encourage you to look at [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/), a modern GUI systems management tool. See [these instructions for installing and launching Cockpit on Fedora](https://cockpit-project.org/running#fedora).